# Typeclass projections as inheritance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to allow typeclasses to be easily "inherited" on union types, by deriving the typeclass automatically when there exists a *projection* (this projection is another typeclass that I defined separately). Below is some code illustrating what I'm trying to achieve:

```hs
class t ##-> a where -- the projection
    inj :: t -> a
    prj :: a -> Maybe t
class Prop t where -- the property
    fn1 :: Int -> t
    fn2 :: t -> t
instance (t #-> a, Prop t) => Prop a where -- deriving the property from the projection
    cst :: Int -> a
    cst = inj . fn1 @t
    fn2 :: a -> a
    fn2 a1 = inj $ fn2 @t $ fromJust (prj a1)
```

And so, when I define a sum type, I can define only the projection `#->`, without redefining the typeclass `Prop` on the sum type.

```hs
data K = ...
instance Prop K
data SumType = E1 K | ...
instance K #-> SumType where
    inj :: K -> SumType 
    inj = E1
    prj :: SumType -> Maybe K
    prj (E1 k) = Just k
    prj _ = Nothing
```

However, I ran into the following problem, when I would like to reuse typeclass functions in the instance definition. For example, when I am trying to give a `Prop` class definition for a base type (say, `String`):

```hs
instance Prop String where
    cst :: Int -> String
    cst = show
    fn2 :: String -> String
    fn2 s = if s == cst 0 then "0" else s -- Overlapping instances for Prop String arising from a use of ‘cst’
```

The compiler isn't sure whether to use the derived type (from the `#->` derivation), or to use the base instance I defined (i.e. the `Prop String` definition). It seems obvious to me however, that in the `Prop String` definition, the `cst @String` definition should be used. Using `{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}` also does not seem to help the compiler determine the instance needed.

I'm wondering how would we go about convincing the compiler to use the instance I intended here?

Comment: Instances of the form `instance (...) => C a` are bad, as a general rule. There should always be a clear instance head to match on. There are other ways to avoid having to write repetitive instance code; for your case it sounds like [generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) would do the trick, together with `DefaultSignatures` (which might also be sufficient by themselves). Othertimes a newtype wrapper or Template Haskell are the way to go.

Comment: @leftaroundabout thanks for the links, I will have a read through them. Wondering if you can explain a bit more about "having a clear instance head to match on"? Is it because one can easily run into ambiguous instances problem like in this question? Do the same apply for classes too e.g. `class (A a, B a) => C a`

Comment: as a follow up: are instances like `instance (Show a) => Show [a]` to be avoided too, or only specifically `instance (..) => C a` (i.e. rather than `C (f a)`)

Comment: Sorry a further followup: why did `TypeApplications` not allow the compiler resolve the instance?